# Who said: "Everything is meaningless, but nothing is chance"?

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request, history-of-philosophy, quote

In the German movie series *Heimat 2* (episode 8), the philosophy student Alex says at one point:

> **Everything is meaningless, but nothing is chance**

[my tentative transcription from German: ***Alles ist sinnlos, aber nicht ist Zufall***].

Is this a quote from a non-fictional philosopher?

Search engines did not yield any hint.

Comment: I doubt any big name said it in those words, they are too cheesy. But it simplistically expresses a conclusion from [hard determinism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_determinism): "everything is meaningless" (no free will to make decisions) but "nothing is chance" (there is no randomness either).

Comment: It sounds more like a joke or a spin on "ëverything is meaningful, nothing is chance" - a platitude easy to find in popular books.